spring-boot-docker-compose - how to "reset" containers before/after use
Is there a way how to reset the container started via spring-boot-docker-compose to original state? I want to, sometimes, delete persisted changes when using a volume.
I really prefer not to modify docker compose files for that.
Something like docker container --rm run ..., ideally settable via pom.xml or an environment variable of the app when I run it from IDE.
